# The dimension of the solution space of the equation $\lambda\, \overline{\partial}f=f$

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain in the complex plane with smooth boundary. Fix $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ and consider the d-bar equation $\lambda\frac{\partial f}{\partial\overline{z}}=f$ in $\Omega$. For practical purposes lets restrict ourselves to solutions in $C^2(\overline{\Omega}).$ What can be said about the dimension of solution to such equation?What if we pose the same question but this time for $\lambda\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=f$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the substitution
$$
f(z) = e^{\bar z/\lambda } \phi(z) \tag{1}
$$
the equation becomes
$$\frac{\partial \phi}{ \partial\bar z}=0$$
which says simply that $\phi$ is holomorphic. So, (1) gives all solutions as $\phi$ runs over holomorphic functions. That's an infinite-dimensional space.

Similarly for the second equation:
 $$
f(z) = e^{ z/\lambda } \overline{\phi(z)} 
$$

Comment: actually after I posted the question,sat down and came up with a similar solution.How would you justify that all solutions are of this form though?

Comment: Any function $f$ is of the form (1) for some $\phi$, because you can divide it by exponential.